# Rails 3: How Lazy Loading really works on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, lazy-loading

I have the following User model on my application (simplified)

> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> ```
> attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :company_id, :role_id  
> belongs_to :company  
> belongs_to :role
> ```
>
> end

My question is: Is my user carrying around all the Company model attributes during all the time of his session or only when a user.company is executed?

I believe the company method exists as a Relation during the session, but I'm not sure.

If my user is indeed carrying his Company object around, is there a way to prevent this from happening and making que database query only when it is actually called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loading(which is by default) means the association methods will be called only when they are required.

So your user object has `company_id` but not `company` object. Whenever it found user.company it will then executes the DB Query.

However you can `eager load` it with `includes` method.

Eager loading is generally helpful when you are loading multiple `users`, and in `view` you will be calling user.company by iterating over `users`, which will run DB query for each call of user.company(i.e. hitting a db query to same table each time). To avoid this eager loading is helpful, so that it loads all company data for all `users` it fetched..

Answer (score 3):

The answer is it depends on how you instantiated your user object and/or whether you've already accessed the association(s). You can use #loaded? to do some introspection. Here are some examples and the results I'd expect based on the code you provided:

```
user = User.last
user.company.loaded?
=> false
user.company   # loads the association
user.company.loaded?
=> true

user = User.includes(:company).last # eager loads the association
user.company.loaded?
=> true
```

Comment: Nice tip, man. I didn't know the .loaded? method. I really appreciate it.